# Unable to properly terminate "while" loop

Tags: c, loops, input, while-loop, terminate

I'm trying out programming in C for the first time, and applying it to some concrete stuff...

The program I'm creating with the problem deals with a while loop. The goal of the program is to calculate the average miles per gallon for a set of trucks. I want it to terminate as soon as -1 is inputted as the number of gallons consumed, but instead I have to input it twice, once for the number of gallons, and once for the number of miles. I have found this input to in fact be used as part of the calculation of the result. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    int tanks, miles;
    float gallons = 0, average = 0, miles_per_gallon = 0;
    tanks = 0;

    while (gallons != -1) {

            tanks += 1;
            miles_per_gallon = (float)miles / gallons;
            average = average + miles_per_gallon;
            printf("The miles / gallon for this tank was %.3f\n",
                   miles_per_gallon);

            printf("Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): ");
            scanf("%f", &gallons);

            printf("Enter the miles driven: ");
            scanf("%d", &miles);
    }

    average /= tanks;
    printf("The overall average miles/gallon was %.3f", average);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is some sample output:

```
C:\>gallons
Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): 12.3
Enter the miles driven: 700
The miles / gallon for this tank was 56.911
Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): 13.4
Enter the miles driven: 666
The miles / gallon for this tank was 49.701
Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): 17.3
Enter the miles driven: 644
The miles / gallon for this tank was 37.225
Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): 15.5
Enter the miles driven: 777
The miles / gallon for this tank was 50.129
Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): -1
Enter the miles driven: -1
The miles / gallon for this tank was 1.000
The overall average miles/gallon was 38.993
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just a friendly note on style, the bodies of your functions and loops should be indented rather than all being in column 1. Programmers in general depend on the proper formatting style to get a feel for the structure and organization of the code, and it makes it much easier to read. Most languages don't enforce this formatting and leave it up to the programmer (one of the reasons I like Python :)

Comment: @Levon: it's actually formatted tolerably in the source view -- it just suffered incredibly in the conversion to markdown. :/ (Incidentally, Python has the same problems if the editor uses mixed tabs and spaces for different levels of indents -- in that case, it is _completely illegible_ to computer and human alike. There's always a tradeoff...)

Comment: @sarnold .. I probably should have checked the source too. Yes, mixing tabs and spaces in Python is a definite no-no, nothing good can come of that.

Comment: Why does the last miles/gallon calculation print?  Shouldn't the loop break immediately?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the sequence of statements in your code is such that the check for the loop's exit condition is not reached until after the second input is requested. You could add a check for `-1` as soon as it's entered, and break out from the loop. Alternatively, you could ask for the miles to be entered ahead of the gallons.

```
for (;;) { /* This is a "forwver" loop; we break out from the middle */

        tanks += 1;
        miles_per_gallon = (float)miles / gallons;
        average = average + miles_per_gallon;
        printf("The miles / gallon for this tank was %.3f\n",
               miles_per_gallon);

        printf("Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): ");
        scanf("%f", &gallons);

        /* This is where you break from the loop: */
        if (gallons == -1) return 0;

        printf("Enter the miles driven: ");
        scanf("%d", &miles);
}
```

Comment: I like the conversion to `for (;;)` to maintain the exit condition. Nice.

Comment: Awesome! It works. Now, just wondering: can the breaking/exiting from the loop be done at ALL with "while" or does conversion to "for" become necessary in this case..?

Comment: @user1490070 Absolutely, you can! I switched to `for(;;)` because it's been the idiomatic form of "forever loop" since K&R's book, but you can certainly use `while (1)` or `do ... while (2!=3)` or something equally silly. You can also use `break` statement to exit the loop and not the program, but in your case it would mean an extra `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

Well you should be able to work it out by yourself, it is easy if you just change your loop or put a if statement after gallons input

```
while (gallons != -1) {

        tanks += 1;
        miles_per_gallon = ( float ) miles / gallons;
        average = average + miles_per_gallon;
        printf("The miles / gallon for this tank was %.3f\n", miles_per_gallon);

        printf("Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): ");
        scanf("%f", &gallons);

        if(gallons==-1){
             printf("Program terminated");
            return 0;
        }

        printf("Enter the miles driven: ");
        scanf("%d", &miles);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for the exit condition after reading gallons. I've made a couple of changes to you code --- because you are only breaking after reading gallons, i've changes the while condition to true. second I changed your test to <=0 as if 0 is entered you divide by `0` which will break your math, and anything less than 0 simply makes no sense. Thirdly I changed the calculation and reporting to after reading the values, so you don't divide by zero

```
  while (1) {

    printf("Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): ");
    scanf("%f", &gallons);
    if(gallons <= 0) break;

    printf("Enter the miles driven: ");
    scanf("%d", &miles);

    tanks += 1;
    miles_per_gallon = ( float ) miles / gallons;
    average = average + miles_per_gallon;
    printf("The miles / gallon for this tank was %.3f\n", miles_per_gallon);
  }
```

Comment: Note that `true` is not C, and will not compile.

Comment: @Len: C99 introduced [`stdbool.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdbool.h#stdbool.h) which provides for `true`, `false`, and the new `_Bool` type.

Comment: @sarnold: true enough, though we see that OP's code doesn't include it, nor does this answer introduce it (nor does OP mention using C99).

Comment: (not that I'm suggesting that we *shouldn't* use modern standards! Don't get me wrong, I just think it may confuse if the OP who's trying out C for the first time tries to follow this advice and gets told `true` doesn't exist.)

Answer (score 0):

```
while (gallons != -1) {
        /* snip */

        printf("Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): ");
        scanf("%f", &gallons);

        printf("Enter the miles driven: ");
        scanf("%d", &miles);
}
```

Note that you only evaluate the *exit criteria* after asking both questions. If you want to avoid asking for the miles, you have to contort your loop a little further. It'll look something like this:

```
while (gallons != -1) {
        /* snip */

        printf("Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): ");
        scanf("%f", &gallons);

        if (gallons == -1)
            break;  /* exit the while loop */

        printf("Enter the miles driven: ");
        scanf("%d", &miles);
}
```

Of course, exiting a loop in the middle like this is a [bit rough around the edges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming#Low-level_structure_programming), but I don't immediately see a more convenient way to terminate the loop without asking the second question.

Comment: Right, but why does the behavior that happens happen?

Comment: @airza: the loop condition is only executed at the top of the loop, every time through. The loop is not automatically terminated the instant the condition is violated.

Comment: The printf MPG call is before the two inputs, so since he entered -1 it should break before it happens again.

Comment: I see, so I have found after my previous comment above, after testing, that I can keep "while" and avoid changing to for provided I give the exit criteria "for (gallons == -1) return 0;". Nice.

Comment: As [dasblinkenlight says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255342/unable-to-properly-terminate-while-loop/11255457#comment14794744_11255434), the specific type of loop and loop conditions you use are very flexible. I prefer his variant of the loop only because it clearly shows that there is an exit buried in the middle of the loop -- mine does not make that very clear. Mine re-states the criteria used to exit the loop, which is keen, but having the criteria in the loop _twice_ means that one of them might be changed in the future and the other forgotten.

Comment: dasblinkenlight's loop is nicer, in my opinion, than mine; it feels more natural to me. But I can understand why it wouldn't feel right to have a loop that _looks_ infinite but isn't...